# URL with 2 parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have website where i put topics, each topic have unique ID and name (name of the topic should be an website). I need to put 2 parameters in URL, first is ID and second a name.

I have this script:

```
 RewriteRule ^topic/([^/]+)$ index.php?page=topic&tipic_id=$1
```

and I want to put before this the name of the topic and then will go a ID. So maybe it will look like this:

```
 RewriteRule ^topic/([^/]+)$ index.php?page=topic&server_id=$1&name=$2 ?
```

But name can be domain for example: example.com and I don't wanna the . in the URL I need to look like this (seo friendly) with ID at the end because I need it for GET parameter later:

```
  http://www.example.com/topic/long-topic-name-id
```

For name I prepared the $name variable.

Thanks for all answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^topic/([^/]+?-)?([^/-]+)$ index.php?page=topic&server_id=$2&name=$1
```